# Cant find Camera when triggering OpenCV script in Python Anywhere hosted server

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pythonanywhere

I have a python script that imports the cv2 module and runs a script to detect face through videocapture(0) by opening the webcam. This script works fine in my localserver but when i have uploaded the file on my pythonanywhere server and try to run the script i get the following error

```
06:50 ~ $ python test.py
[ WARN:0] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (874) open VIDEOIO(V4L2): can't find camera device
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

I looked around the pythonanywhere forums but got no luck. Please either suggest me a way to do so in PythonAnywhere or provide me a different solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pythonanywhere is running your code on different machine which obviously is not connected with webcam so it is showing device not found.you need to send your webcam streaming data to server and process the result

Comment: please can you help me with some links that are closer to my query